# How do I create a 2D array in Perl?

Tags: arrays, perl, perl-data-structures

I am trying to create a 2d array in Perl

my code:

```
my @wordsList=();
my @words=();

for ($id=0; $id<=@language.length; $id++)
{

        my $eng = $db->selectall_arrayref("select word from words 
                                                    left outer join language
                                                    on words.languageId = language.languageId
                                                    where words.languageId = $id
                                                    ;");


        foreach $eng(@$eng)
        {   
        my($word) = @$eng;
        $ref_to_Array->[$id][$word] = @words($id,$word);

            }
                return $words($id, $word);
}

$wordsList= NextWords();
print $wordsList;
```

it returns non.. because I want to return the 2d array.

**Update**

I am still confused because when I execute the query, it gives me a list of words like :

```
select word from words where language_id = 1 
(1=english, 2 - chinese, 3 - french)
```

I am using the for loop through the language and in order to get all the words from the database

The problem is I want to loop and want the array is added to the 2d array automatically.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Place `use warnings; use strict;` at the top of every program you write.  Those two pragmas will catch many errors for you.

You can't access an array with a `(...)` postfix.  That construct is used to call functions `mysub(...)` or `$mysubref->(...)`.  To access array elements, you use a postfix `[ index ]`.  And in Perl, multi-dimensional arrays require a pair of `[...]` for each level.  This is because a 2D array is simply an array where each element is also an array.

```
my @array = ([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]);

my $top_left     = $array[0][0];  # 1
my $bottom_right = $array[2][2];  # 9

print "@$_\n" for @array;
```

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

You can learn more about Perl's data structures and the rest of Perl at [perldoc.perl.org](http://perldoc.perl.org).  Here are a few direct links:

- arrays of arrays: [perllol](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllol.html)
- complex data structures: [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html)
- [general language reference](http://perldoc.perl.org/index-language.html)

Finally, `@language.length` does not do what you think it does.  It is taking `@language` in scalar context, which is its length as a number and then concatenating it with `length($_)`.  The resulting expression is something like `(scalar @language) . length($_)`.  Since the `<=` operator imposes scalar context on its arguments, you could simply write `$id <= @language`.  However, Perl provides you with a more natural way of writing this type of loop:

```
for my $id (0 .. @language) {...}
```

or

```
for my $id (0 .. $#language) {...}
```

if you really meant `$id < @language` since `$language[scalar @language]` is one element past the end of the array.